# External request limit on IIS

Tags: django, iis, python-requests

I have deployed django application on IIS. The application requests external link (API) to extract some data.

What I have seen is, it makes requests but fails to complete full request. It goes for about 4 request sometimes it goes further 9 requests and stops there. No sign of error is shown.

While I perform same task from django shell, all requests are made. So I guess this is something related to IIS.

I am new to IIS and windows server app deployment.

I tried googling about this but I could not find any relevant answer.

Did anyone of you here faced similar problem? If so what can be the solution. Also can you guide me on this?